# SQL Update query

Tags: sql, sql-update

Can i use several `WHEN` conditions in `UPDATE` clause to update a single column.

I want to update table TABLE having columns ID and NAME:

Is below query correct?

```
UPDATE TABLE 
   SET id = CASE id
              WHEN id IN (2, 3, 4) THEN 1
              WHEN id= 5 THEN 8
              WHEN id IN(9, 7) THEN 6
 WHERE name = 'abc'
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that is allowed, but remove `ID` after `CASE`. And, you need to `END` your case.

```
UPDATE TABLE 
SET ID = CASE  
    when ID in (2,3,4) 
        then 1 
    when ID = 5 
        then 8 
    when ID in (9,7) 
        then 6 
END
where NAME = 'abc'
```

There are two alternate syntaxes for CASE. As above, and the other is where you want to compare a single value against others, like this:

```
UPDATE TABLE 
SET ID = CASE ID 
    when 2
        then 1 
    when 5 
        then 8 
    when 7
        then 6 
END
where NAME = 'abc'
```

Comment: +1 You're describing [Simple vs Searched CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Case comes in two versions:

version 1:

```
 Case Id
     When 2 Then 1
     When 3 Then 1
     When 4 Then 1
     When 5 Then 8
     When 7 Then 6
     When 9 Then 6
     End
```

version 2:

```
 Case    
   When Id in (2,3,4) Then 1   
   When Id = 5        Then 8   
   When Id in (9,7)   Then 6   
 End
```

Both of above are equivilent